# handshake_failure no suitable certificate found

Tags: java, ssl

i'm using java 8 for ssl connection got 8 RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure
the sever owner sent me three cert files i added them to key store and trust store.
using System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",  file);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", file);
error below is ssl debug output

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
```

VWarning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
    *** Certificate chain

appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: Seems like the server is requesting client certificate authentication, and your client doesn't have a certificate to send. You'll need to specify a keystore in PKCS12, JKS, JCEKS format containing the client's keypair.

Comment: thanks for prompt reply.they gave three certificates  files i imported them in KS file but it doesn't work.it there is another way to generate key from cert files

Comment: It would be worth adding that detail to the question. Also add how you have specified the keystore in your program.

Comment: thanks for reply i set set my key store file  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "client_from_server2.jks");

Answer (score 3):

The key to this is right here:

```
Cert Authorities:
     <Empty>
```

The server doesn't trust anybody. It has an empty truststore, or no truststore at all. The client can only send a certificate that is trusted by the `Cert Authorities` in the `CertificateRequest` message. There were no authorities, so no client certificate, so no TLS session.

Solution: fix the server truststore.

Comment: EJP, I'm experiencing a similar problem as stated above in the question. But,I do have the Certificate Authorities as :



`Certificate Authorities

<CN=Composer Client, OU=Genesys Composer, O=Genesys Composer, L="Chennai ", ST=TN, C=IN>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 171
 06  ...Chennai 1.0..
0070: 6D 70 6F 73 65 72 31 19   30 17 0
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 0 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>`

Comment: Though I have the Certificate Authorities, I'm facing a similar issue .  Can you please advise on this ?

Your help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: @Raguram If you have non-empty certificate authorities you *aren't* facing a similar issue.

Comment: I'm having empty cert authorities as posted above in the question. 





-----
`Cert Authorities:
<Empty>`
---

Comment: The list of Cert Authorities is not empty for my server. I don't why i still see the same error for my client.  *** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=XYZ>
<CN=XYZClientCA, O=XYZ Inc.>
<CN=XYZServerCA, O=XYZ Inc.>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 363